# one of my HTML scripts not working in IE

Tags: php, batch-file

For some reason, when i run this in IE it just displays everything other than the embedded php code,
does anyone know what I should do?  Here is my code:

```
//Server stats display code:
// The page must be refreshed to get most recent checks.
<b>
Server Stats: |Runs every 10 minutes.|
<?php
check:
exec('C:\Users\<name>\Desktop\serverstats.bat');
include("C:\Users\<name>\Desktop\serverstats.txt");
sleep(600);
goto check;
?>
</b>
//.bat contents: |Just embed this somewhere in your site and set the directories.|
//@echo off
//ping 192.168.0.11 > C:\Users\<name>\Desktop\serverstats.txt
```

Comment: You must run it from web server with installed PHP. IE itself have no idea what it is, so that it interprets this as plain text

Comment: He's newbie to PHP and this website. Ppl please be kind instead of writing useless stuff in comments

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language. It does not have any browser dependency. If you are 100% sure that it works in other browsers, and not in IE, the issue will be with the surrounding HTML code. The code block you provided does not have any such browser dependent HTML though.

Since you said "it just displays everything other than the embedded php code", your server must have PHP installed and configured.

You are not seeing any of the PHP content because your PHP is generating some error, and your PHP settings are masking the error. The first thing to do is, turn on error_reporting by adding the following to your PHP code :

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

That will give you where the error is.

Check the path to your include file. That is one possiblity.

Comment: okay, my friend patched it today to and said host that script and then go to the url and execute it, and yes i barely just learned php